# Jenkins does not come with Docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm starting to learn Jenkins and I'm following the guide on their website. This is a new Jenkins install, installed all the recommended plugins. I've created a valid Jenkinsfile, initialized git in the project folder, and I'm trying to build, however, Jenkins doesn't seem to find Docker. When building, I get:

```
/Users/me/.jenkins/workspace/Test_pipeline_master@tmp/durable-ba04c9ec/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
```

Am I supposed to install a separate docker installation? I'm checking and I do have Docker plugin:

[image]

My Jenkinsfile has:

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'node:7-alpine' } } #also tried with python:3.7 to no avail
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install docker if you are planning to use docker.
Once installed, you also need to add the user 'jenkins' to docker group.
See these two links for more help.
(if you are installing jenkins on other OS, search for appropriate help for installing docker for that OS)

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04

https://www.edureka.co/community/7764/trying-docker-jenkins-pipeline-facing-jenkins-pipeline-socket

Comment: Ah thanks, I though the Jenkins plugin would install Docker so as to be used with Jenkins, but I guess it just allows to call Docker from Jenkins. Gotcha.